# How can I save a table with unicode characters to pdf in R

Tags: r, unicode, r-markdown, xelatex

I want to create a table in an adobe acrobat file with unicode characters like ≥ and ±.
I used xelatex and saved with the encoding="UTF-8" parameter like suggested in other questions on stackoverflow.

```
#' ---
#' title: "Cannot render Unicode"
#' author: "Robert"
#' date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
#' geometry: margin=1cm
#' output:
#'   html_document:
#'      toc: true
#'      highlight: zenburn
#'   pdf_document:
#'     toc: true
#'     number_sections: true
#'     highlight: zenburn
#' documentclass: article
#' classoption: a4paper
#' ---
#'
#+ include = F
library(pander)
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)

panderOptions('digits', 2)
panderOptions('round', 2)
panderOptions('keep.trailing.zeros', TRUE)
options(Encoding="UTF-8")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE)

sd=sprintf('%.01f',runif(n = 12, min = .25, max = .75))
mn=sprintf('%.01f',1:12+runif(n = 12, min = .25, max = .75))
vals = paste0(mn,' \U00B1 ',sd)

df = tibble(col1=rep(c('a < 1','a \U2265 1'),6),mnsd=vals)

#' A table with merged rows
#' 
#+ results='asis', echo=FALSE
ft = flextable::flextable(df) %>%
  set_header_labels(col1 = "comparisons", mnsd = 'mean  \U00B1 sd') %>%
  empty_blanks() %>%
  theme_box() %>%
  autofit()
ft
```

I saved the code above in a file called unicodeBug.R and ran the command below to create a pdf document.

```
rmarkdown::render("./unicodeBug.R",output_file="unicodeBug.pdf",output_format='pdf_document',encoding="UTF-8")
```

The ≥ and ± aren't displayed correctly in these files. Does anyone have any suggestions?

The code is run on Windows 10. Further sessioninfo:

> sessionInfo() R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) Platform:
>   x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build
>   18363)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    [3]
>   LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1] janitor_1.2.1   forcats_0.5.0
>   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.5     purrr_0.3.3      [6] readr_1.3.1
>   tidyr_1.0.2     tibble_3.0.0    ggplot2_3.3.0   tidyverse_1.3.0 [11]
>   flextable_0.5.9 officer_0.3.8   pander_0.6.3
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6
>   lubridate_1.7.4   lattice_0.20-38   ps_1.3.2           [5]
>   assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.25     utf8_1.1.4        R6_2.4.1
>   [9] cellranger_1.1.0  backports_1.1.5   reprex_0.3.0
>   evaluate_0.14     [13] httr_1.4.1        highr_0.8
>   pillar_1.4.3      gdtools_0.2.1     [17] rlang_0.4.5       uuid_0.1-4 
>   readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.11   [21] data.table_1.12.8 callr_3.4.3
>   rmarkdown_2.1     webshot_0.5.2     [25] tinytex_0.22
>   munsell_0.5.0     broom_0.5.5       compiler_3.6.3    [29]
>   modelr_0.1.6      xfun_0.12         pkgconfig_2.0.3
>   systemfonts_0.1.1 [33] base64enc_0.1-3   htmltools_0.4.0
>   tidyselect_1.0.0  fansi_0.4.1       [37] crayon_1.3.4
>   dbplyr_1.4.2      withr_2.1.2       grid_3.6.3        [41]
>   nlme_3.1-144      jsonlite_1.6.1    gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_0.2.0 
>   [45] DBI_1.1.0         magrittr_1.5      scales_1.1.0      zip_2.0.4
>   [49] cli_2.0.2         stringi_1.4.6     fs_1.3.2          xml2_1.2.5 
>   [53] ellipsis_0.3.0    generics_0.0.2    vctrs_0.2.4       tools_3.6.3
>   [57] glue_1.3.2        hms_0.5.3         processx_3.4.2    yaml_2.2.1 
>   [61] colorspace_1.4-1  rvest_0.3.5       knitr_1.28        haven_2.2.0

Comment: works fine on macOS, will check windows tomorrow.

Comment: Suggestion:  don't use Windows, or don't use R.  R has *never* handled non-native characters properly on Windows.